# Codable Classes from Swift to Json (@Published & @StateObject)

Tags: arrays, json, swift, xcode, swiftui

My endgame is to `print` this object (below) like this in the console from the data in my app which is connected with @Published & @StateObjects.

The Object I want to create to eventually send via api (api part out of scope).  One Object called `"household"` with a few different arrays: `receiving_benefits`, `utility_providers`, `person_details`, `incomes`, `assets`.

```
{
"household": {
    "region": "PA",
    "household_size": 1,
    "receiving_benefits": [
    ],
    "energy_crisis": false,
    "utility_providers": [
        "peco"
    ],
    "residence_type": "other",
    "property_tax_past_due": false,
    "home_needs_repairs": false,
    "filed_previous_year_tax_return": false,
    "heating_system_needs_repairs": false,
    "at_risk_of_homelessness": false,
    "received_maximum_benefit": {
        "cip": false
    },
    "person_details": [
        {
            "age": 18,
            "marital_status": "single",
            "minimum_employment_over_extended_period": false,
            "work_status": "recent_loss",
            "pregnant": false,
            "attending_school": false,
            "disabled": false
        }
    ],
    "incomes": [
        {
            "gross_monthly_amount": 700,
            "countable_group": "household",
            "year": "current"
        },
        {
            "gross_monthly_amount": 700,
            "countable_group": "household",
            "year": "previous"
        }
    ],
    "assets": [
        {
            "amount": 1000,
            "countable_group": "household"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

The classes I have in a file called Eligible are the follow, but I'll only expand on the ones I believe are important:

```
class Incomes : ObservableObject, Codable {...}

class Assets : ObservableObject, Codable {...}

class Person_details : ObservableObject, Codable {...}

class Received_maximum_benefit : ObservableObject, Codable {...}

class Base : ObservableObject, Codable {
    @Published var household: Household?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case household = "household"
    }
    
    init() { }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(household, forKey: .household)
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        household = try container.decode(Household.self, forKey: .household)
    }
}

class Household : ObservableObject, Codable {
    @Published var region: String = ""
    @Published var household_size: Int = 1
    @Published var receiving_benefits : [String]?
    @Published var energy_crisis : Bool = false
    @Published var utility_providers: [String] = [""]
    @Published var residence_type : String = ""
    @Published var property_tax_past_due : Bool = false
    @Published var home_needs_repairs : Bool = false
    @Published var filed_previous_year_tax_return : Bool = false
    @Published var heating_system_needs_repairs : Bool = false
    @Published var at_risk_of_homelessness: Bool = false
    @Published var received_maximum_benefit : Received_maximum_benefit?
    @Published var person_details : [Person_details]?
    @Published var Income : [Incomes]?
    @Published var assets : [Assets]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case region = "region"
        case household_size = "household_size"
        case receiving_benefits = "receiving_benefits"
        case energy_crisis = "energy_crisis"
        case utility_providers = "utility_providers"
        case residence_type = "residence_type"
        case property_tax_past_due = "property_tax_past_due"
        case home_needs_repairs = "home_needs_repairs"
        case filed_previous_year_tax_return = "filed_previous_year_tax_return"
        case heating_system_needs_repairs = "heating_system_needs_repairs"
        case at_risk_of_homelessness = "at_risk_of_homelessness"
        case received_maximum_benefit = "received_maximum_benefit"
        case person_details = "person_details"
        case Income = "incomes"
        case assets = "assets"
    }
    
    init() { }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(region, forKey: .region)
        try container.encode(household_size, forKey: .household_size)
        try container.encode(receiving_benefits, forKey: .receiving_benefits)
        try container.encode(energy_crisis, forKey: .energy_crisis)
        try container.encode(utility_providers, forKey: .utility_providers)
        try container.encode(residence_type, forKey: .residence_type)
        try container.encode(property_tax_past_due, forKey: .property_tax_past_due)
        try container.encode(home_needs_repairs, forKey: .home_needs_repairs)
        try container.encode(filed_previous_year_tax_return, forKey: .filed_previous_year_tax_return)
        try container.encode(heating_system_needs_repairs, forKey: .heating_system_needs_repairs)
        try container.encode(at_risk_of_homelessness, forKey: .at_risk_of_homelessness)
        try container.encode(received_maximum_benefit, forKey: .received_maximum_benefit)
        try container.encode(person_details, forKey: .person_details)
        try container.encode(Income, forKey: .Income)
        try container.encode(assets, forKey: .assets)
    }
    
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        region = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .region)
        household_size = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .household_size)
        receiving_benefits = try container.decode([String].self, forKey: .receiving_benefits)
        energy_crisis = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .energy_crisis)
        utility_providers = try container.decode([String].self, forKey: .utility_providers)
        residence_type = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .residence_type)
        property_tax_past_due = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .property_tax_past_due)
        home_needs_repairs = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .home_needs_repairs)
        filed_previous_year_tax_return = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .filed_previous_year_tax_return)
        heating_system_needs_repairs = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .heating_system_needs_repairs)
        at_risk_of_homelessness = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .at_risk_of_homelessness)
        received_maximum_benefit = try container.decode(Received_maximum_benefit.self, forKey: .received_maximum_benefit)
        person_details = try container.decode([Person_details].self, forKey: .person_details)
        Income = try container.decode([Incomes].self, forKey: .Income)
        assets = try container.decode([Assets].self, forKey: .assets)
    }
}
```

And the following are the @StateObjects in my content view connected to the classes:

```
@StateObject var eligBase = Base()
@StateObject var user = Household()
@StateObject var personDetails = Person_details()
@StateObject var Income = Incomes()
@StateObject var Asset = Assets()
@StateObject var RMB = Received_maximum_benefit()
```

Once I select a button inside the ContentView, I have the following that is prints the data into the console in json pretty format:

```
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted


        do {
            let data = try encoder.encode(user) 
            print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!) 
        } catch {
            print("fail")
        }
```

has you can see based on the @StateObjects, when I ask it to encode 'user', which is the Household class, it doesn't print out the `Income`, `Assets` or `PersonDetails` arrays etc and only prints out the other @Published variables in the Household class like so:

```
{
  "filed_previous_year_tax_return" : true,
  "heating_system_needs_repairs" : false,
  "household_size" : 1,
  "assets" : null,
  "home_needs_repairs" : false,
  "person_details" : null,
  "utility_providers" : [
    "pgw"
  ],
  "energy_crisis" : false,
  "incomes" : null,
  "receiving_benefits" : null,
  "region" : "PA",
  "residence_type" : "rent",
  "received_maximum_benefit" : null,
  "at_risk_of_homelessness" : true,
  "property_tax_past_due" : false
}
```

I've tried to printing out the `Base` class but only prints out the following:

```
{
  "household" : null
}
```

Basically, not sure what I'm doing wrong or how I can recreate that payload at the top of this question but once I'm able to create that payload I'll be able to send with a API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve your `endgame`, my advice is restructure your code such that you do not use these as separate classes:

```
class Incomes : ObservableObject, Codable {...}
class Assets : ObservableObject, Codable {...}
class Person_details : ObservableObject, Codable {...}
class Received_maximum_benefit : ObservableObject, Codable {...}
class Household : ObservableObject, Codable {...}
.....
```

Declare these as `struct`, not `ObservableObject` class. See sample code.

Similarly do not use these separate `StateObject`:

```
@StateObject var user = Household()
@StateObject var personDetails = Person_details()
@StateObject var Income = Incomes()
@StateObject var Asset = Assets()
@StateObject var RMB = Received_maximum_benefit()
```

You already have all you need in `class Base : ObservableObject, Codable {...}`.

Keep `class Base` as it is, together with `@StateObject var eligBase = Base()`
and use those throughout your code. Finally use `Base` (eligBase) in your json encoding.

Sample code:

```
struct Household: Codable {
    var region: String
    var householdSize: Int
    var receivingBenefits: [String] 
    var energyCrisis: Bool
    var utilityProviders: [String]
    var residenceType: String
    var propertyTaxPastDue, homeNeedsRepairs, filedPreviousYearTaxReturn, heatingSystemNeedsRepairs: Bool
    var atRiskOfHomelessness: Bool
    var receivedMaximumBenefit: ReceivedMaximumBenefit
    var personDetails: [PersonDetail]
    var incomes: [Income]
    var assets: [Asset]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case region
        case householdSize = "household_size"
        case receivingBenefits = "receiving_benefits"
        case energyCrisis = "energy_crisis"
        case utilityProviders = "utility_providers"
        case residenceType = "residence_type"
        case propertyTaxPastDue = "property_tax_past_due"
        case homeNeedsRepairs = "home_needs_repairs"
        case filedPreviousYearTaxReturn = "filed_previous_year_tax_return"
        case heatingSystemNeedsRepairs = "heating_system_needs_repairs"
        case atRiskOfHomelessness = "at_risk_of_homelessness"
        case receivedMaximumBenefit = "received_maximum_benefit"
        case personDetails = "person_details"
        case incomes, assets
    }
}

struct Asset: Codable {
    var amount: Int
    var countableGroup: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case amount
        case countableGroup = "countable_group"
    }
}

struct Income: Codable {
    var grossMonthlyAmount: Int
    var countableGroup, year: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case grossMonthlyAmount = "gross_monthly_amount"
        case countableGroup = "countable_group"
        case year
    }
}

struct PersonDetail: Codable {
    var age: Int
    var maritalStatus: String
    var minimumEmploymentOverExtendedPeriod: Bool
    var workStatus: String
    var pregnant, attendingSchool, disabled: Bool

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case age
        case maritalStatus = "marital_status"
        case minimumEmploymentOverExtendedPeriod = "minimum_employment_over_extended_period"
        case workStatus = "work_status"
        case pregnant
        case attendingSchool = "attending_school"
        case disabled
    }
}

struct ReceivedMaximumBenefit: Codable {
    var cip: Bool
}
```

EDIT

[1], now that we are using structs for `Household` and its constituents , the `init()` and encoding and decoding are all done for us.
There is no need for complicated code here, unless there is some specialised processing to be done.

[2],  here is some test code that shows how to read and write your `Base`(eligBase)  model.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var eligBase = Base()
    
    let json = """
{
"household": {
    "region": "PA",
    "household_size": 1,
    "receiving_benefits": [
    ],
    "energy_crisis": false,
    "utility_providers": [
        "peco"
    ],
    "residence_type": "other",
    "property_tax_past_due": false,
    "home_needs_repairs": false,
    "filed_previous_year_tax_return": false,
    "heating_system_needs_repairs": false,
    "at_risk_of_homelessness": false,
    "received_maximum_benefit": {
        "cip": false
    },
    "person_details": [
        {
            "age": 18,
            "marital_status": "single",
            "minimum_employment_over_extended_period": false,
            "work_status": "recent_loss",
            "pregnant": false,
            "attending_school": false,
            "disabled": false
        }
    ],
    "incomes": [
        {
            "gross_monthly_amount": 700,
            "countable_group": "household",
            "year": "current"
        },
        {
            "gross_monthly_amount": 700,
            "countable_group": "household",
            "year": "previous"
        }
    ],
    "assets": [
        {
            "amount": 1000,
            "countable_group": "household"
        }
    ]
}
}
"""
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("demo")
            .onAppear {
                print("---> reading Json \n")
                readJson()
                print("---> writing Json \n")
                writeJson()
            }
    }
    
    func readJson() {
        do {
            let elig = try JSONDecoder().decode(Base.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
            eligBase.household = elig.household
            print("\n----> eligBase.household: \(eligBase.household) \n")
        } catch {
            print("---> error: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func writeJson() {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
        do {
            let data = try encoder.encode(eligBase)
            if let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("\n----> str: \(str) \n")
            }
        } catch {
            print("---> error: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
}
```

EDIT

Have reshaped the code slightly for easy data interaction and show how to use a TextField for changing `grossMonthlyAmount`.

Changed `household` in `Base` as not optional, and updated the array structs to be `Identifiable`
to make it easier to interact with the data. Also put the reading of the data in the `Base` model.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var eligBase = Base()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 44) {
            Text("Region " + eligBase.household.region)
            Text("Total income: \(eligBase.household.incomes.reduce(0){ $0 + $1.grossMonthlyAmount})")
            List {
                Section("Income") {
                    ForEach($eligBase.household.incomes) { $income in
                        TextField("", value: $income.grossMonthlyAmount, formatter: NumberFormatter())
                            .keyboardType(.numbersAndPunctuation)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}

class Base: ObservableObject, Codable {
    @Published var household: Household  // <-- here
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case household = "household"
    }
    
    // -- here simulated initial reading of data from db or server --
    init() {
        self.household = Household(region: "", householdSize: 0, receivingBenefits: [], energyCrisis: false, utilityProviders: [], residenceType: "", propertyTaxPastDue: false, homeNeedsRepairs: false, filedPreviousYearTaxReturn: false, heatingSystemNeedsRepairs: false, atRiskOfHomelessness: false, receivedMaximumBenefit: ReceivedMaximumBenefit(cip: false), personDetails: [], incomes: [], assets: [])
        
        readHousehold()
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(household, forKey: .household)
    }
    
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        household = try container.decode(Household.self, forKey: .household)
    }
    
    // --- here ---
    func readHousehold() {
        let json = """
     {
     "household": {
         "region": "PA",
         "household_size": 1,
         "receiving_benefits": [
         ],
         "energy_crisis": false,
         "utility_providers": [
             "peco"
         ],
         "residence_type": "other",
         "property_tax_past_due": false,
         "home_needs_repairs": false,
         "filed_previous_year_tax_return": false,
         "heating_system_needs_repairs": false,
         "at_risk_of_homelessness": false,
         "received_maximum_benefit": {
             "cip": false
         },
         "person_details": [
             {
                 "age": 18,
                 "marital_status": "single",
                 "minimum_employment_over_extended_period": false,
                 "work_status": "recent_loss",
                 "pregnant": false,
                 "attending_school": false,
                 "disabled": false
             }
         ],
         "incomes": [
             {
                 "gross_monthly_amount": 700,
                 "countable_group": "household",
                 "year": "current"
             },
             {
                 "gross_monthly_amount": 700,
                 "countable_group": "household",
                 "year": "previous"
             }
         ],
         "assets": [
             {
                 "amount": 1000,
                 "countable_group": "household"
             }
         ]
     }
     }
     """
        do {
            let elig = try JSONDecoder().decode(Base.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
            household = elig.household
        } catch {
            print("---> error: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    // --- here ---
    func writeHousehold() {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
        do {
            let data = try encoder.encode(household)
            if let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("\n----> str: \(str) \n")
            }
        } catch {
            print("---> error: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
}

struct Asset: Codable, Identifiable {  // <-- here
    let id  = UUID()  // <-- here
    var amount: Int
    var countableGroup: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case amount
        case countableGroup = "countable_group"
    }
}

struct Income: Codable, Identifiable {  // <-- here
    let id  = UUID()  // <-- here
    var grossMonthlyAmount: Int
    var countableGroup, year: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case grossMonthlyAmount = "gross_monthly_amount"
        case countableGroup = "countable_group"
        case year
    }
}

struct PersonDetail: Codable, Identifiable {  // <-- here
    let id  = UUID()  // <-- here
    var age: Int
    var maritalStatus: String
    var minimumEmploymentOverExtendedPeriod: Bool
    var workStatus: String
    var pregnant, attendingSchool, disabled: Bool
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case age
        case maritalStatus = "marital_status"
        case minimumEmploymentOverExtendedPeriod = "minimum_employment_over_extended_period"
        case workStatus = "work_status"
        case pregnant
        case attendingSchool = "attending_school"
        case disabled
    }
}
```

Comment: A couple questions:  [1] seems like you've taken the init() { }, encodes & decodes out of the structs, is there a reason for that?  [2] when I placed the structs into the ContentView and try to print (Base), I receive a single value in the json, "household": null....any reason why to this as well?  Thanks!

Comment: And you're right, I don't fully understand it.  If you have any literature or sites that are a valuable resource to you, please share :-)

Comment: updated my answer with some example code, to show how to read and write your `Base` model.

Comment: Hey, Thank you for this.  Btw, any reason you may think that the arrays are coming up empty?

  "household" : {
    "assets" : [

    ],
    "person_details" : [

    ],
    "utility_providers" : [
      ""
    ],
    "energy_crisis" : false,
    "incomes" : [

    ],
    "receiving_benefits" : [

    ],
    "region" : "PA",
    "residence_type" : "rent",
    "received_maximum_benefit" : {
      "cip" : false
    },
    "at_risk_of_homelessness" : false,
    "property_tax_past_due" : false
  }
}

Comment: if the arrays are empty for you, it's because you haven't copy my code properly. It all works well for me, all the data is showing as it should, including all the arrays.

Comment: Copying the code exactly makes me have to redo a lot of my variable bindings.  With that said, if I want to now connect, say a toggle() to one of the variables in the Incomes struct, I'd  connect by $eligBase.gross_monthly_income ? Not sure how I'm connecting TextFields, toggles to their respected variables in structs.

Comment: Have updated the code to show how to use a TextField for changing `grossMonthlyAmount`.
Note, there is no `toggle` possible in the `Income` struct, it's `Int` or `String`, no `Bool`.